# Android - Listview divider with specific width

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, divider

I want to add dividers to listview with specific width, like the foursquare app on tips list:

[image: preview]

I don't know the proper way to do it, i tried adding a line on bottom of each item view, but the last item have a divider too, i know its a wrong way.

Is there any way to make the divider width the same of the text content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any arbitrary Drawable  as a divider by calling ListView's [`setDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDivider%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method. If you know the width of the content you intend to display you can use that knowledge to make an appropriate graphic.

Also be aware that you will need to call `setDividerHeight()` if the drawable does not have an intrinsic height.